# Запятая перед придаточным из одного слова

Tags: пунктуация

Будьте добры, нужна ли запятая: Он раздражен, как думаешь(,) почему?

Answer (score 1):

***Он раздражен, кАк думаешь, почемУ?***

Запятая не ставится в таких предложениях: ***Он раздражен, но я не знаю почемУ.***

В приведенном предложении два вопросительных слова, они не могут находится в одной интонационной фразе, ударение падает на каждое из них.